# What command can I use to generate a Lingering Potion item with specific radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Normally with `/summon` command I can generate a Lingering Potion Cloud Effect that does what I want:

```
/summon minecraft:area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Radius:5,Duration:10000,Effects:[{Id:5,Amplifier:0,Duration:60}]}
```

But I want a `/give` command for a lingering potion that does the same thing.

Is it even possible?

Comment: I assumed it would simply be `CustomPotionEffects` instead of `Effects`, but it turns out that doesn't affect the resulting lingering cloud. This is an interesting puzzle.

Comment: Continued research suggests that you're not able to alter the NBT of the resulting cloud from within the potion. Someone more experienced than me will have to attempt this, because I haven't been able to get it working.

Comment: Im trying with some nbt editors but failed

Comment: @Corsaka You are correct. It is not possible to set AEC properties using tags on the potion. The only way is to make commands that modify the AEC after it is spawned.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lingering_Potion), the only tags on Lingering Potions in item form are:

- `Potion`, for setting the lingering potion to one of the default potions
- `CustomPotionEffects`, for choosing your own effects, and changing their duration and amplifier
- `CustomPotionColor`, for setting the colour of the potion

The Lingering Potion as an item, unfortunately does not accept any fields to configure properties of the Area Effect Cloud that it produces when it is thrown. In fact, an earlier paragraph on the wiki page reads:

> The cloud starts with a radius of 3 blocks, decreasing to 0 over the course of 30 seconds. During the cloud's existence, any player or mob that walks into it after the first second gets the corresponding status effect; this decreases the radius by a <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> block immediately, causing the cloud to disappear quicker.
>
> For effects with duration, the duration applied by the cloud is <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub> that of the corresponding potion. For effects without duration such as healing or harming, the potency of the effect is <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> that of the corresponding potion.
>
> The effect may be applied consecutively if the player or mob remains in the cloud. For example, a player throwing the Lingering Potion of Healing II straight down consumes the cloud within a few seconds while being healed 5 times for a total of 20♥ × 10 health. As far as healing is concerned, this makes the lingering potion much more powerful than the regular or splash potion, provided that the player is away from other mobs or players.

This paragraph shows that the values are likely hardcoded within the game:

- `Radius`, the AEC's current radius, starts at 3.
- `RadiusPerTick` is set to `-0.005`, if my math is correct.
- `RadiusOnUse` is set to `-0.5`.

Other tags are also probably set to default values too.

To accomplish a task, you would need to set up a command system that modifies the Area Effect Cloud *after* it is spawned. Such systems are usually quite complex and it is out of the scope of this question. If you would like more information, feel free to reach out.